# proper subset of rationals with empty boundary

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, self-learning

This is a question from Analysis by Beals: show there exists a proper subset $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ with empty boundary (my definition of boundary is $\bar{A} \cap \bar{A^c}$, ie. intersection of the closure with the closure of the complement).

I'm having some trouble thinking about this. I was thinking about taking a singleton $a$, which is its own closure, but then we could construct a sequence $a - 1/n$ which converges to $a$, so $a$ would be in the closure of its complement and thus would not have empty boundary. I tried a few other things but cannot get to an answer. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Is your space $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$?  If you consider $x$ so that $x^2 < 2$ you get a set with no boundary in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @fleablood doesn't say :( I would guess $\mathbb{R}$. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: The boundary can also be written as $\overline{A}\setminus A^\circ$. For a subset of $\Bbb{Q}$, you have $A^\circ =\emptyset$ and hence $\partial A =\overline{A}$, which is never empty if $A$ is not empty.